# How to delete column's brackets when generating scripts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Environment: SQL Server 2017

My steps:

- choose database
- right-click
- choose Tasks --> Generate scripts

The tool will generate my SQL scripts like this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Brand]
SET [id] = <id, int,>
   ,[name] = <name, nvarchar(10),>
GO
```

I don't need brackets `[]` around my id and name column when generate many columns, how do I close or set somewhat in SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think there is any such option. After the script is generated you can use find and replace to find `\]|\[` with the "use regular expressions" option and replace it with an empty string. If any of your identifiers don't meet the naming standards for regular identifiers (e.g. is a key word or contains a space) this may leave invalid syntax though

Comment: I think you are right! Because I search on google and I can't find related information.Thank you advice!